# Errai - Separate client and server code

Tags: java, maven, gwt, errai

For past GWT projects, I've used this [archtype](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) for creating a 3 module project. It separates client code, server code, and code shared between both. This allowed for much faster development as you didn't have to recompile the entire project everytime you made a server side change.

Now, I'd like to use Errai to take advantage of its more natural templating system. I've tried my best to just import the errai-ui and related dependencies, but I couldn't get that to work. After searching around, it seems that Errai is designed to be used as a framework and not as a library. You can see my SO question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810640/use-errai-ui-with-gwt).

I found [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199437?tstart=0) where someone did exactly what I needed. Though, they didn't post at all how they did it.

I found [this guide](https://github.com/mbarkley/gwt-to-errai-tutorial) which shows how to add Errai to an existing GWT project, but this assumes that your GWT project is setup in a standard single module, which is what I don't want.

My main problem is that I don't know what is needed in the pom files to make this work. I only want to use Errai's client side features, such as errai-ui and errai-navigation, so I figure Errai stuff can live solely in the client module. When generating a new Errai project though, there's just so much stuff in the pom, and I don't know how to transfer that to the parent and client pom's.

Ideally, I just need an example or skeleton project to get me going. If these things just don't exist, a hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand this question might be better suited for a forum, but I've tried to post to the Errai (JBoss) forum and an admin would not admit my post. If more details are needed, I can provide them.

Comment: I would recommend starting with the basic tutorial, and getting a feel of errai before you start imposing your own architecture. Anyway it boils down to use the suggested tutorial setup as your "client" project. Your server project doesnt need anything if you dont want to use the parts involving the server like events/marshalling aso. Same for your "shared" project. I have an older errai project in a public repository maybe it helps https://bitbucket.org/k5_/greenfield/src/e1e5d744dcd82e1e90e41b03d8d1973d62413d46/strategem/?at=default

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Maven and to have a parent and child projects like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>APP::Parent</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>client</module>
  <module>server</module>
  <module>shared</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

This way your server codes and client codes are separated and import the `shared` dependency into  the `client` and `server`

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's work when You wonna use only errai on the client. It won't work for server side or shared side.